# How do I formalize a personal investment in a friend's business?

Tags: investing, legal

I am going to invest in a friend's business.  What documents do we need to sign in order to be safe legally in the future?

Comment: A tag of **401k**?

Comment: Are you asking what documents the business needs in order to operate legally?  What documents you need in order to make sure he pays you back?  Also, what country are you in?  If the US, what state?  Will you be investing with cash?  All at one time?  What's the time horizon over which you expect to be paid back?

Comment: What documents i will need in order to make sure he will pay me back. This time i am in USA on visit but basically i belong to Pakistan and here only on business trip, the state in which i am investing is Maryland, i will send the money through his bank account by Telegraphic Transfer, all at one time or may be two transactions, initially for two years   period i am investing with him. Waiting thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing does not sound like an investment; it sounds like a loan.

An investment involves you putting up a stake and sharing in the profits *or* losses of the business - there is *no* guarantee you will get your money back.

A loan involves you putting up money for which you will receive interest and principal repayment in accordance with an agreed schedule - you get this irrespective of how the business is performing.

Also, is the arrangement with your friend or his company? They are different legal entities and your risk profile is different in both cases.

Whatever the arrangement you need to sign a contract which details all the terms and conditions - how much you will pay, to whom and when; how much you will get back, from whom and when; a method for resolving disputes; what happens in the event of insolvency or bankruptcy; what happens if someone breaks the terms of the contract; if your payout depends on the value of the business at some future date, how it is to be valued; etc. etc.

Two points:

1. Think very, very carefully before going into a silent partnership with a friend - know going in if you place a higher value on the money or the friendship.
2. Hire a lawyer.

I am not a lawyer, I am not your lawyer.

Comment: More important, the OP should hire a lawyer of his own and not rely on the advice of any lawyer that is hired by his friend, whether personally or as the attorney for the business. Also, I suspect that the OP, presumably a citizen of Pakistan and therefore subject to Pakistani law, cannot legally _lend_ the money (and charge interest); it must be either a gift, or an investment.